# How was time mapped before they used "BBY" in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars

In the Star Wars universe, time is measured by using "BBY": before battle of Yavin... however, seeings as there was a lot of history before that, including but not limited to:

- The Old Republic
- The New Republic (prequels)
- The First Galactic Empire- & the events of a New Hope incl. battle of 
  Yavin.

How was time measured in that (thousands of years) time period before the battle of Yavin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time in Galactic Standard Calendar is determined by number of solar cycles of planet Coruscant around particularly important events.

I couldn't find a complete list of such events, but here goes, from oldest to newest:

1. Founding of the Republic (Old Republic, 25,053 BBY)
2. Numerous major conflicts in 7000, 5000, 3976, 3958, 3681
3. **Treaty of Coruscant (3653 BBY)**
4. **Ruusan Reformation (1000 BBY)**
5. Great ReSynchronization (35 BBY)
6. Founding of the Galactic Empire (19 BBY)
7. **Battle of Yavin (0)**

25 ABY, the New Republic sought to standardize the Galactic Calendar, and since then, Battle of Yavin is the Year Zero.

[Further info can be found here, at Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Galactic_Standard_Calendar)

Comment: ^_^ You did a much better job than I did at presenting the information.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots thanks. On a side note, it's a wonder anyone knows what the hell year it is, given how many events are out there. Before 25ABY, people probably used various dates, someone walks up to you and goes "there's going to be a Famous Band performance in 1020ARR!" and you're wondering "what the hell is ARR"

Comment: True, although I don't know that it's that different from the range of events that have been used here on Earth. The Julian/Gregorian calendars are relatively recent Western innovations and are not used universally.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots true, its much like our own. However, we'd be 25ABY+ galaxy - almost the entire world uses Gregorian calendar (Battle of Yavin), and most people would barely be able to recall 3 other calendars, much less use them. Meanwhile, pre-25ABY galaxy was a free-for-all.